# How can I tell if a JSON string has no elements, in Perl?

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to compare a string to another.

If it's a JSON structure which contains things, I want to print "contains things".
If it's a JSON structure which doesn't contain thing, I print "empty"
If it something which is not between curly brackets "{}", i print that there's an error.

Here's what I've done :

```
if($content =~ m/{.+}/){
    print "Contains things \n";
} elsif($content eq "{}"){
    $job_status{$url}="";
    print "empty \n";
} else {
    print "Error \n";
}
```

When I pass "{}" to the variable $content, he does not enter the "elsif", but go to the "else", and throw an error.

I've tried to put "==" instead the "eq" in the if, even though I know it's for numbers. When so, he enters the "elsif", and print "empty", like he should do with the "eq", and throws :

```
Argument "{}" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)".
```

I could use the JSON library, but I prefer not to.

Comment: Have you done any other debugging? Try printing out the $content variable: `echo " '" . $content . "' ";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Does `$content` have a newline character?  Try `chomp $content;`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $content = '{}';
if($content =~ m/{.+}/s){
    print "Contains things \n";
} elsif($content eq "{}"){
    print "empty \n";
} else {
    print "Error \n";
}

__END__

empty
```

Comment: I added the `/s` modifier so the `.` could match a newline. Without that you could have valid, non-empty JSON but end up in the `else` branch. Overall, this isn't a good way to check things because you don't know that the string is valid JSON, and you don't know where those braces show up. Are they syntax or data?

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate the behaviour if I add a newline after the `{}`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $content = "{}\n";

if($content =~ m/{.+}/s){
    print "Contains things \n";
} elsif($content eq "{}"){
    print "empty \n";
} else {
    print "Error \n";
}
```

It returns "Error", if I replace `eq` with `==`, it returns `empty`, because both `"{}"` and `"{}\n"` are numerically 0. A warning is thrown as you mentioned.

You might try to [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) the `$content` before processing it.

Comment: Your answer is correct ! I chomped it with this line before the "if"
`chomp($content);` 
and it resolved my problem.
toolic said it first, so I accepted his answer, but yours is OK too.

Comment: Same comment I made for @toolic. You need the `/s` to get past any newlines in the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Heh, I don't like my answer from 8 years ago. Today I'd prefer to just check the JSON:

```
use v5.36;
use experimental qw(builtin);
use builtin qw(reftype); # or get it from Scalar::Util

use JSON;

my @inputs = (
    '{', '}', 'abc',
    '{}', '{"a":"b"}',
    );

foreach my $input ( @inputs ) {
    my $json = eval { decode_json( $input ) };

    my $empty =
        defined( $json ) &&
        ( reftype $json eq reftype {} and 0 == keys $json->%* );

    say "INPUT: $input --> ", $empty ? 'Empty' : 'Not empty (or not JSON)';
    }
```

And, there's `jq` if you are outside of a program:

```
$ jq '. == {}' <<< "{}"
true

$ jq '. != {}' <<< "{}"
false
```

---

A top-level JSON thingy can be an object (`{...}`) or an array (`[...]`), but you're only checking for one of those. If you merely want to see if it's empty, I'd check the length of the string:

```
chomp $possible_json;
if( $length $possible_json >= 3 ) { ... }
```

You might also consider Randal Schwartz's [regex for JSON parsing](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=995856). It doesn't handle everything, but it's often enough for simple things.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably end up breaking it up:

```
unless ($content) {print "Error\n"};
$content =~ /{(.*)}/
my $resp = $1;
if ($resp) {
 print "Contains Things ($resp)\n";
} else {
 print "Empty\n";
}
```

Comment: This way, you can get both `Error` and `Empty`.

Comment: You're right, I was try not to make 2 regexes and still get everything while having the contents. I'm just not coming up with a clean way of making that happen.